# Why is my dll not loaded in this JAVA code?

Tags: java, native

I have the following code that is supposed to load two dlls:

```
public class ArcgisJniNet {
static{
System.load("D:/Users/User/Desktop/DLL/comCorporateProject.dll");
System.load("D:/Users/User/Desktop/DLL/FileGDBAPI.dll");
}

//Native method declaration
 private native void FileGDBApi();


public void test(){
ArcgisJniNet arcgisJniNet = new ArcgisJniNet();
arcgisJniNet.FileGDBApi(); 
}
}
```

However, when I deploy in karaf and run the service call, it throws the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
D:\Users\User\Desktop\DLL\comCorporateProject.dll: Can't find dependent 
libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)[:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)[:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)[:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)[:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)[:1.8.0_162]
at com.corporate.ex.services.arcgis.service.ArcgisJniNet.<clinit> 
(ArcgisJniNet.java:5)
```

I already set in environment variable to include the path to the dll folder and restarted my computer but seems like I am still faced with this issue.

My C++ implementation looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "comCorporateProject.h"

#include <FileGDBAPI.h>
using namespace FileGDBAPI;
using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_com_corporate_ex_services_arcgis_service_ArcgisJniNet_FileGDBApi
(JNIEnv *, jobject) {
fgdbError   hr;
Geodatabase gdb;
if ((hr = 
CreateGeodatabase(L"D:/Users/User/Desktop/geodb/example.gdb", gdb)) != 
S_OK)
 {
    wcout << "An error occurred while creating the geodatabase.";       
 }
 wcout << "An error occurred while creating the geodatabase.";
 CloseGeodatabase(gdb); 
}
```

My intention is to invoke the c++ function from the java code jar that will be deployed in the server. I'm not sure why it is telling me it cannot find the dll when I have provided the right absolute path. Please point out the mistake I have made. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: It isn't telling you it cannot find the DLL. It is telling you 'can't find dependent 
libraries', which means *another* DLL that that DLL depends on.

Comment: Oh Thanks. This actually helps. I added other dlls and it can load now. :)